# Wifi Antenna for a boat

Tags: wifi

I've a question concerning a Wifi antenna with special needs / requirements.

My computer is in a sailing boat, and I want to connect to the public wifi of the port. The signal is not always good because of the distance, and of course, the sailing boat is made of aluminium which doesn't help to get a good signal in it.

I'm thinking to add a Wifi antenna outside on the boat to connect to the public wifi and then connect or get wired to this outside antenna. Since the antenna will be outside, I also need it to be waterproof.

I've seen there is wifi antenna which can be connected with USB, but USB cable cannot be longer than 5 meters according to the specification, which is probably too short.

Since I won't always stay in the same port, it should be also easy to connect (to configure) to new public wifi.

What do you suggest me?

Comment: How far from the WAP are you usually?

Comment: I believe it would be usually between 50 and 200 meters, but it hardly depends of the port and where the boat is.

Answer (score 1):

Idea (haven't done this myself): Buy a dedicated outdoor router that supports power over ethernet (e.g. from Ubiquity or TP-Link). Those routers should already be at least somewhat weatherproof. Fix at top of mast, run ethernet cable through mast, add power-over-ethernet device somewhere in cabin. Connect to another router (which will create a hotspot, or provide LAN ports) inside as desired.